# Using Linq to find the element after a specified element in a collection

Tags: c#, linq

I have an ordered list of People.  I have a person that I know exists in that collection.  How can I determine which person is next in the list?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
IEnumerable<Person> persons = ..

var firstPersonAfterJack = persons.SkipWhile(p => p.Name != "Jack")
                                  .ElementAt(1); //Zero-indexed, means second
```

The idea is to produce a sequence resulting in skipping elements until you meet the condition, then take the second element of *that* sequence.

If there's no guarantee that the query will return a result (e.g. a match is never found, or is the last element of the sequence), you could replace `ElementAt` with `ElementAtOrDefault`, and then do a `null`-test to check for success / failure.

I notice you say in your question that you have an *ordered* list of people. If you could explain what that means in more detail, we might be able to provide a better answer (for example, we may not have to linear-search the sequence).

Comment: @finnw: We even chose the same property name. Imagine if we'd chosen the same person name too. :)

Comment: This is a great solution for a generic Linq to Object query, but the `SkipWhile` query operator is not supported in Linq to Sql.

Answer (score 5):

`SkipWhile` is a method that takes a predicate and skips everything until the predicate is false. It returns that element and everything after.

```
var remainingPeople = collectionOfPeople.SkipWhile(p => !isThePerson(p));
if (remainingPeople.Count() == 1)
{
    // the person was the last in the list.
}
var nextPerson = remainingPeople.Skip(1).First();
```

where `isThePerson` is a method that takes a person and returns true if it is the person you are interested it.

Comment: There are 2 issues here: 1) There is a redundant enumeration of the *entire* source sequence. 2) It will fail when `remainingPeople.Count() == 0` i.e. the condition is never satisfied.

Comment: 1) I don't see where it enumerates the entire sequence twice. Can you point out where? 2) It will fail if it's not in the list but the requirements say the person is guaranteed be in the list so it's not a problem.

Comment: Remember that most LINQ operators use deferred execution. `remainingPeople` is a *query*, not a list or array. It's results are retrieved twice, once for `Count()` and once for `Skip(1).First()`.

Comment: I tested and you're right. I knew it was deferred but I had no idea it would reevaluate each time. I've spent too much time with Haskell laziness.

Answer (score 0):

You can use code like this:

```
String toDir = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs().SkipWhile(x => x != "/to").Skip(1).Take(1).FirstOrDefault();
```

This value gets `== null` if `"/to"` command line argument not given, `non-null` if path was provided.