# Pulling duplicate rows based on column in Notepad++( or via C#)

Tags: c#, regex, notepad++

I have a file that have some duplicate sequence numbers. What I want to do is have only my duplicates show. My file looks something like this:

```
John Doe    000115   
Wilson Chan 000386
Tye Owens   000589
James Peter 000211
Carl Spade  000445
Sally Doe   000213
```

The sequence number starts at the 15th place and ends at the 17th place. My desired output is:

```
James Peter 000211    
Sally Doe   000213
```

Sally and James both of the sequence of 02.
I am completely new with regex and only figured out that `^(.{15})[^-](.*)$` gets me to the 15th place. I am stuck after that.
Is there a way to accomplish this in notepad++ or via VBS?

Comment: Are they consecutive? Try `^.{15}(\d{2}).*(?:\R.{15}\1.*)+`

Comment: They are not always consecutive, thanks for bring up that point, I have edited my question.

Comment: OK, it is not a job for a regex. You might split the text into lines, create key-values with the keys being the substrings of length 2 at index 15, then group and get those with count more than 1. In C#, it is relatively easy (for me). Not sure how to do it in VBScript.

Comment: I'm willing to give that a try, I have some exposure to C#, could you coach me through it?

Comment: I will try to come up with a fiddle

Comment: See https://ideone.com/BRPTxa

Comment: The 15th place through the 17th place is 3 characters - why is the sequence just two?

Comment: @NetMage, it's just how the file is, the other characters have other meanings.

Comment: You said "The sequence number starts at the 15th place and ends at the 17th place". Then you said "Sally and James both of the sequence of 02". Both statements cannot be true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A regex approach is not advisable when you are looking for dupes like this, you may write a small program, say, in C#, to split the text into separate lines, create key-value pairs out of the lines, with the keys being the substrings of length 2 at Index 15, then group and get those with count more than one.

```
var txt = @"John Doe    000115   \nWilson Chan 000386\nTye Owens   000589\nJames Peter 000211\nCarl Spade  000445\nSally Doe   000213";
var splits = txt.Split('\n') // Split into lines 
    .Select(m => new KeyValuePair<string,string>(m.Substring(15,2), m)) // Create key value pairs
    .GroupBy(z => z.Key)   // Group by the 2-char substring
    .Where(y => y.Count() > 1);  // Grab only those with the same key
foreach (var x in splits)        // Display the groups
{
    Console.WriteLine("--- {0} ---", x.Key);
    foreach (var y in x)
        Console.WriteLine(y.Value);
}
```

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/BRPTxa)

Output:

```
--- 21 ---
James Peter 000211
Sally Doe   000213
```

Comment: Thanks, for the help, I used you're solution against a text file.

Comment: @Ichigo: Then why  not accept my solution? You posted the same solution with your own custom values, why?

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought I did accept you're solution, I added my own solution because I mentioned that I was reading from a file. I wanted to add the solution in case someone else needs to read a file and not just a string of text. I have rechecked your solution as the answer.

Comment: @Ichigo Reading from a file is a trivial thing. There are a lot of ways to read a file, `File.ReadAllText(path)` is what you really can do on your own, the core is the parsing code.

Comment: @ Wiktor Stribiżew Ok,out of curiosity, how powerful are lambda expressions? I've never really used them. If I were to only want  Sally Doe 000213 as the output, because she came after James Peter 000211 in the file, is that possible?

Comment: @Ichigo: That is unclear. Sally Does must be returned because there is a specific item in the list just before it? I guess you can use the solution described at [Using Linq to find the element after a specified element in a collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4653634/).

Comment: @ Wiktor Stribiżew: Yes, Sally Doe must be returned because there is a specific item in the list before it. In this case, the specific item is the sequence number of "02". Because James Peter already has that sequence, Sally shows up on the output. I will study the solution you linked.

Answer (score 1):

You have a flat file, fixed width, database. Since you mentioned a .NET language, you can use the OleDb namespace to convert the text file to a DataTable, then you would filter out any unique values. Here are the steps to do that:

1. Create a new [OleDbDataConnection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection(v=vs.110).aspx)

   1. The connection string should follow the format for [Fixed Length Columns](https://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-jet-ole-db-4-0/fixed-length-columns/)
   2. The connection string's data source would be the directory in which the file resides.
2. Create a new [OleDbCommand](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand(v=vs.110).aspx) using the OleDbConnection from step 1

   1. The command string should be: `SELECT DISTINCT * FROM [file_name].txt`
3. Create a new [OleDbDataAdapter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdataadapter(v=vs.110).aspx) using the OleDbCommand from step 2
4. Use the OleDbDataAdapter's [Fill method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5s322715(v=vs.110).aspx) to fill the contents of the fixed width database into a [DataTable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable(v=vs.110).aspx)

I would provide you an example, but I am more fluent in Visual Basic .NET. If you prefer, I can edit my post to include the VB.NET example and you could run it through a converter.

**Update**

Since you requested the Visual Basic .NET example, here is a function that would convert the file to a DataTable:

```
''' <summary>
''' Converts a fixed width database to a .NET DataTable
''' </summary>
''' <param name="path">The location of the text file to convert</param>
''' <param name="headers">Indicates if the fixed width database contains a header row</param>
''' <returns>DataTable</returns>
''' <remarks>Only returns unique rows</remarks>
Private Function ConvertToDataTable(ByVal path As String, ByVal headers As Boolean) As DataTable
    If Not IO.File.Exists(path) Then
        Throw New ArgumentException("The file does not exists.", "path")
    End If

    'Declare an object to return
    Dim dt As DataTable = Nothing

    'Create a connection object
    Dim con As OleDbConnection = Nothing

    'Database junk, always wrap in Try/Catch
    Try
        'Create a new instance the database connection
        con = New OleDbConnection($"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0;Data Source={IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(path)};Extended Properties=""Text;HDR={If(headers, "Yes", "No")};FMT=Fixed"";")

        'Create a new instance of a command object
        Using cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand($"SELECT * FROM {path}", con)
            'Create a new instance of a dataadapter
            Using adapter As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
                'Open the connection
                con.Open()

                'Create a new instance of a DataTable
                dt = New DataTable

                'Fill the data into the DataTable
                adapter.Fill(dt)

                'Close the connection
                con.Close()
            End Using
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString())
    Finally
        'Check if the connection object was initialized
        If con IsNot Nothing Then
            If con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                'Close the connection if it was left open(exception thrown)
                con.Close()
            End If

            'Dispose of the connection object
            con.Dispose()
        End If
    End Try

    'Return the converted DataTable
    Return dt
End Function
```

Since the file is a fixed width file, you would have to pair it with an `Schema.ini` file as well. In your case the `.ini` file would look like this:

```
[path_name_nere.txt]
Format=FixedLength

Col1=Column1 Text Width 12
Col2=Column2 Text Width 6
```

Now that the file has been converted to a DataTable, you'd filter the DataTable to exclude the duplicates.

Comment: OleDbDataConnection sounds like a very useful tool, if you can, I would love if you added your VB.NET example.

Comment: I have edited the post to include the VB.NET example.

Answer (score 0):

with [Wiktor Stribiżew's help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46857237/5292302), this is the solution I used:

```
 var text = File.ReadAllText("C:\\johndoe.txt");
 var sw = new StreamWriter("C:\\johndoeduplicates.txt");
 var splits = text.Split('|')
 .Select(m => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(m.Substring(14, 2), m))
 .GroupBy(z => z.Key)
 .Where(y => y.Count() > 1);
  foreach (var x in splits)
  {  
      foreach (var y in x)
       sw.WriteLine(y.Value);
  }
  sw.Close();
```